# Was Morse code the first practical application of binary encoding of information?

Tags: mathematics

As I understand schemes for sending different symbols over different wires were implemented but the simplicity of Morse's dot or dash made it the easiest to read and/or implement. It seems similar to early computer design have instead of binary digits decimal representation which ultimately were impractical because the precise machining necessary was too expensive.

(Perhaps the Jacquard loom was another example but I do not think there were competing designs -- I am interested in binary winning out over competing approaches.)

Comment: Morse is not actually a binary code. The spaces between letters are a third symbol.

Comment: @BenCrowell: but it is ultimately connected or unconnected, no?

Comment: I don't know how practical or useful it was, but there is the 1605 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bacon%27s_cipher